# ENV VAR in HOCON include statement

Tags: typesafe-config

I'd like to do the following

```
include file(${HOME}/.oat/db_local_dev.conf)
```

Unfortunately, it gives the following error:

```
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse: /Users/XXXX/src/oat3/conf/shared.local.conf: 16: expecting a quoted string inside file(), classpath(), or url(), rather than: '${'HOME'}'
```

The documentation at https://github.com/typesafehub/config does not say the argument to include must be a string, but I think I remember reading that someplace in the past.

So...  Any workarounds?  If not, can someone at least explain why this limitation is here?  Some sort of security hole?  It's the only reason I can think of for omitting such a useful feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot dynamically include another properties file.

> An include statement consists of the unquoted string include followed
> by whitespace and then either:
>
> - a single quoted string which is interpreted heuristically as URL,
>   filename, or classpath resource.
> - url(), file(), or classpath() surrounding a quoted string which is then interpreted as a URL, file, or classpath. The string must be quoted, unlike in CSS.
> - required() surrounding one of the above

see official docs: https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#includes

Also see (**Feature request: dynamic includes #122**): https://github.com/lightbend/config/issues/122

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issues list for lots of background on why this isn't supported.

Answer (score -3):

A working syntax would be

```
include "file://${HOME}/.oat/db_local_dev.conf"
```

which is using an explicit UR to reference the configuration file.